# Qt GUI application crashes calling QThreadPool start two times

Tags: qt, qrunnable

I'm trying to use QThreadPool on a QRunnable-base class
The code is the following

```
void Window::on_randomBtn_clicked()
{
    QString value;

    _pool.start(_randomizer);
    _pool.waitForDone();
    value = _randomizer->value();

    ui->RVal->setText(value);
    _red.setRgb(value.toInt(), 0, 0);


    _pool.start(_randomizer);
    _pool.waitForDone();
    value = _randomizer->value();

    ui->GVal->setText(value);
    _green.setRgb(0, value.toInt(), 0);
...
```

In the above code `_pool` is an instance of `QThreadPool` and `_randomizer` an instance of a class `Randomizer` which extends `QRunnable`.
The `run` method of the `Randomizer` is just a oneliner producing random numbers

I can't understand why but what happens is just a SIGABRT signal received by the application after calling the second time the `_pool.start(_randomizer)`

I've also tried to instantiate two different `Randomizer` objects but the same behavior holds.

Could you help me explaining why?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example to reproduce your issue. From your pieces above noone can help you.

Comment: Note that by default [`QRunnable::autoDelete`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html#autoDelete) returns true, so dereferencing `_randomizer` after calling `_pool.waitForDone()` is undefined behaviour.